# Tutorial to create Shapefile based on Districts using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, references

I have been tasked to create shapefile of Amritsar, India (will be incorporated into [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/))

[image]

So far, I see this [2-part video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUnUrTzP2dw), where person is assigning numbers and icons, and drawing in roads, but I don't see where he is separating a place into districts.

I've been searching endlessly, please point me in the right direction

Most likely I will use ArcGIS for Desktop via a 2 month free evaluation.

Comment: Have you search it on the internet about R ? I am sure there are a lot of them that you can find. https://www.r-project.org/

Comment: @PROBERT R program is where I will reference the shapefile once it's created. R is a statistical program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to identify information about digitizing polygons if you insist on digitizing this yourself. It could be as easy as digitizing the outer polygon and then using the "Split" tool to split that polygon multiple times.

In an edit session, with an existing polygon, the split tool can be used to split the tool into 2 equal parts. You have to start and end completely outside the polygon (effectively splitting it). It will fail if it cannot identify all parts of the selected polygon as being either in or out. Looking at the drawing in the question, it appears that you could digitize the outer polygon first and then achieve the desired result by splitting the polygon multiple times.

Another possibility for you would be to download the information that you seek.

if you go to http://www.gadm.org/ and then click the "Download" tab, and choose "India" under country. You will see that you can then select your preferred format for download (shapefile etc.). There are 4 layers in the download for India and they have boundaries broken down at multiple levels. I downloaded this and viewed it in QGIS without any problem.

[image: Basic political boundaries]

[image: More detailed political boundaries]

You should be able to export data for just the boundary you need (excluding the rest) in ArcMap or QGIS.

Comment: This sorta helps me answer my question. I checked the shape file, and I'm not sure it's as granular as I'm looking for (Amritsar is a district in a state itself!). But this is something I can work on for now.

Comment: I hope it gives you a good place to start. Be sure to look at all 4 shapefiles since there is more detail there. I could edit my answer further to help with your digitizing workflow if that is helpful.

Comment: Yes,if you can edit answer to further help with digitizing workflow that will be great!